# Render function after document ready at vueJS

Tags: vue.js, wysiwyg

I want to initiate Wysiwyg dynamically by clicking the button at VueJS app.
With condition: if users already click more than twice.
But there are errors "Cant convert null object ......" 
How can I run the function when the object is ready at VueJS?
here is my example code:

```
<button @click="addMore"> Add Wysiwyg </button> 
<fieldset v-for="(u, index) in a": key = "index">
    <textarea 
    :id='"emailwysiwyg"+index'
    name="body_email">
    </textarea>
</fieldset>
var App = new Vue({
    data: {
        addCount: 1
    }
    mounted() {
        if (addCount >= 2) {
            this.InitiateWysiwyg('#emailwysiwyg' + this.addCount, 'body_email')
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addMore() {
            addCount++
        },
        InitiateWysiwyg: function(el, field_name) {
            // function to InitiateWysiwyg
        },
    }
})
```

Please help.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduction on Stackblitz or Codepen. Why never know why you are getting _"Cant convert null object ......"_.

Comment: The whole thing with index/addCount looks flaky. It's not guaranteed that #emailwysiwyg' + this.addCount is the same as "emailwysiwyg"+index . All sane third-party libs allow to provide DOM element instead of a selector, and you can use template refs to refer DOM elements, that's how it's normally done